# QuickChick context forwarding

Tags: coq

I have a problem with QuickChick testing framework.
Suppose I have a type like this:

```
Inductive f := f1 (x : Z) (range : x < 20 /\ 0 < x).
```

And two functions like this:

```
Definition boundaries' (t : bool) :=
  if t 
  then (1, 10)%Z 
  else (10, 19)%Z .

Program Definition binary_gen (t : G bool) : G (f) :=
  bindGen ((fmap boundaries') t) (fun '(m_min, m_max) =>
    bindGen (choose (m_min, m_max)) (fun (x : Z) =>
        returnGen (f1 x _))).
```

When I want to prove missing proof object I have this context:

```
t : G bool
z, z0, x : Z
============================
x < 20 /\ 0 < x
```

The problem is that when using `bindGen` I loose context from before that I need to prove current goal.

So the question is, how to forward context using `bindGen` or are there any workarounds around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is a `bindGen'` combinator](https://github.com/QuickChick/QuickChick/blob/d029099e63f0040c8536feb187a45128ff881830/src/GenLowInterface.v#L91):

```
Definition bindGen' : forall {A B : Type} (g : G A), 
                       (forall (a : A), (a \in semGen g) -> G B) -> G B.
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was searching for.